# 403 Response Status Code, Error Code 220, while using request module with Twitter API

Tags: javascript, twitter

I am trying to make a POST request to Twitter using the Javascript request module and am getting a 403 error. I am able to complete GET requests successfully. So, I am not sure why my attempt to post a status update is being rejected.

```
var request = require('request');

function postTweet(tweet) {
    var options = {
        uri: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=hi',
        method: 'POST',
        oauth: oauth,
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': 'request',
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    }
    request(options, function(err, response, tweet) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(response.statusCode);
        }
    });
}
```

To clarify, I have had success posting status updates using the Twitter module, so I am pretty sure all of my authorization keys are correct. I get error code 220, with message: "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource." My application's settings are read, write, and direct messages.